# Writing a character with amnesia

Tags: creative-writing, comics, emotions

I'm working on a webcomic in which the main character has amnesia from head trauma. She was an experiment and when escaping she hit her head. She has one sentence of dialogue to the other main character saying that "she's in a hurry" before she passes out, and when she wakes up she realizes that she can't remember anything except she had a feeling that there's something important that she needs to do.

I'm having trouble writing the dialogue for when she realizes she can't remember anything from her life before this moment. I'm not sure what emotions I should channel as she's a very excited and happy character in general.

Answer (score 0):

### Meet cute!

Build the chemistry between your 2 main characters. Amnesia or not, establish what makes them click from the start.

If they spar comedically..., or one-side flirts..., or they share a love of vintage baseball memorabilia… whatever it is, give it in its purest form here.

Maybe amnesia girl is smart enough to cover a vulnerability. She might decide that Manic-Pixie-Dreamgirling her way into his heart like a rom-com is as good a plan as any until she remembers what she was doing.

Maybe she didn't have a real plan other than 'escape', and being outside for the first time she has so many questions. She would prolong the experience as long as she can. Depending on how clever or manipulative or entertaining she is, she might say anything to string him along, or she follows him and he slowly realizes she's making up information about herself as he tries to get rid of her.

Unfortunately, real amnesia is traumatic brain damage, so there are no 'realistic' ways to do this trope.

Comment: i like the idea of just upping the chemistry to like..avoid the issue, except that my comic is a superhero/sci-fi and the amnesia is a large part of the first arc. (also the romance is queer fyi, both girls).

Comment: About realistic portrayal, I don't know the statistics but based on friends' experience,  I'm under the impression that the more common type of amnesia is anterograde, and for some reason I've never seen that in fiction, always retrograde. (And always extreme cases of that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your character is like an alien just arrived on Earth. Depending also on how much she forgot.

What's this? How does it work? Where is this town? Who are these people and why do they behave like that?

It's a good way of showing how humanity works from the outside. People do random acts of evil and of kindness.

She will be full of curiosity and eager to learn. Some things will make her wonder, some will remind her of things she no longer knows.